# Как подтянуть функцию к другому классу

Tags: java, функции

У меня есть класс Main, в котором есть функция getConfig(), есть еще один класс AddToList, как мне сделать так, чтобы функцию из основного класса, можно было использовать в другом?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

import org.bukkit.configuration.Configuration;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.utils.MemberCachePolicy;


/*
* AutoBan java plugin
*/
public class Plugin extends JavaPlugin  {
 File config = new File(getDataFolder() + File.separator + "config.yml");
 
private static final Logger LOGGER=Logger.getLogger("AutoBan");




   

public void init() {
   
   try {
       @SuppressWarnings("unused")
     JDA jda = JDABuilder.createDefault("token")
                 .setMemberCachePolicy(MemberCachePolicy.ALL)
                 .addEventListeners(new EventListener())
                 .build();
       
   } catch(LoginException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
public void onEnable() {
 
 LOGGER.info("Made by ");
 if(!config.exists()) {
     LOGGER.warning("Plugin configuration NOT detected, creating..");
     getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
     saveDefaultConfig();
     LOGGER.info("Plugin configuration created, please check is.");
 }
 init();
 LOGGER.info("AutoBan enabled");
}

public void onDisable() {
 LOGGER.info("AutoBan disabled");
 LOGGER.info("Made by ");
}
}
```

Comment: Что такое "подтянуть"?

Comment: Я имел в виду чтобы функцию из основного класса, можно было использовать в другом

Comment: Какое отношение код имеет к вопросу? Вы написали, что есть класс `Main` и `AddToList`, а выложили `Plugin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1й вариант создать объект и вызвать у него метод

```
Main main = new Main();
main.getConfig();
```

2й вариант объявить метод с ключевым словом static

```
static void getConfig() {}
```

и вызвать через класс

```
Main.getConfig();
```

Comment: Мне выдает This static method cannot hide the instance method from JavaPlugin, что делать?

Comment: возможно конфликт имён методов, или ещё что-нибудь. без кода понять невозможно

Comment: Сюда код не влезает, конфликтов нету

Comment: что значит не влезает?

Comment: Он больше чем ограничение по символам

Comment: вопрос можно отредактировать

Comment: Отредактировал.